# How to use URLDownload if the url doesn't have the correct filetype extension?

Tags: files-and-directories, web-access

I'm using the new (in V11) function `UrlDownload[]`

[image]

I have a url I'd like to save to a local file, but the url is missing a (or has the incorrect) filetype extension. So I don't know how to construct the filename properly. Here's an example:

```
url = "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRf1EqE2kyW12HSb9gZZ8eTIPqNgVkjFis4GkTTYONIpoQtkIde4zybZ4iAqGlIHQ_pnEX499Oa";
Import@url
URLDownload[url, "~/Downloads/" <> ToString@RandomInteger[1000000]]
```

[image]

I'd like to save it with the proper extension though. Any thoughts?

Also, URLDownload doesn't seem to be multithreaded, this is waaay too slow:

[image]

Comment: For a faster way to download files check out `URLSaveAsynchronous`. If the file type appears in the URL or not is immaterial, just append the right file extension to your file name.

Comment: @C.E. and what is the right extension (and how do you detect that)?

Answer (score 5):

If I was downloading different types of images and I couldn't find out what their file types are a priori I'd do something like this perhaps:

```
url = "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:\
ANd9GcRf1EqE2kyW12HSb9gZZ8eTIPqNgVkjFis4GkTTYONIpoQtkIde4zybZ4iAqGlIHQ\
_pnEX499Oa";

callback[file_][_, "data", _] := (
  If[FileFormat[file] == "JPEG", CopyFile[file, "path/to/new/image.jpg"]];
  DeleteFile[file];
  )

file = CreateFile[];
URLSaveAsynchronous[url, file, callback[file]];
```

`URLSaveAsynchronous` is an asynchronous operation as the name suggests, which means that you can download many files simultaneously. I use `CreateFile` to create an empty file in my operating system's directory for temporary files and pass a custom callback function, using that file, to `URLSaveAsynchronous`. When `URLSaveAsynchronous` has downloaded the file it calls the callback function, which subsequently detects the file format using `FileFormat`, copies the file to wherever it's supposed to go, with the right file extension, and then deletes the file in the temporary directory.

Comment: you can get an idea of the extension via the following: `Last@StringSplit[(Association@@URLRead[url,"Headers"])["content-type"],"/"]`

Comment: @chuy ok, but why would I want to do that though? He says he needs to be able to download files in parallel, and `URLRead` is not asynchronous.

Comment: `URLSubmit` is asynchronous and can tell you the `"ContentType"` directly.  I've never used it through, nor am I familiar with how content types work.

Comment: `FileFormat` is nice though because it looks at the magic bytes.